# Apagar informações em um elemento HTML com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Quando escrevo as informações no quadro de cima (`input`), ele automaticamente aparece em baixo. Porém ao apagar as informações de cima ele não apaga as de baixo.

Já tentei colocar um botão de redefinir, porem ocorre a mesma coisa, ele só apaga as informações de cima.

Alguém poderia me da uma ideia ou exemplo de como posso fazer apagar todas as informações e começar de novo?

**Código:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    Nome <input id='nome' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Cont 1 <input id='fixo' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Cont 2 <input id='contato' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Problema <input id='problema' type='text' value=''
  onkeyup="insere()" />
<br><br><br> problema continua
<br><br><br>
<p>
  Cliente: <span class="cliente"></span><br> 
  Contatos: <span class="tel"></span>\<span class="cont"></span><br>  descrição do problema: <span class="pro"></span>
</p>
<br><br><br> problema resolvido
<br><br><br>
<p>
  Cliente: <span class="cliente"></span><br> 
  Contatos: <span class="tel"></span>\<span class="cont"></span><br> descrição do problema: <span class="pro"></span>
</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cliente = document.getElementById('nome');
var fone = document.getElementById('fixo');
var contato = document.getElementById('contato');
var problema = document.getElementById('problema');

var cliente1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[0];
var cliente2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[1];

var tel1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tel')[0];
var tel2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tel')[1];

var cont1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cont')[0];
var cont2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cont')[1];

var pro1 = document.getElementsByClassName('pro')[0];
var pro2 = document.getElementsByClassName('pro')[1];


function insere() {
 
  if (cliente.value !== '') {
    cliente1.innerHTML = cliente.value;
    cliente2.innerHTML = cliente.value;
  }

  
  if (fone.value !== '') {
    tel1.innerHTML = fone.value;
    tel2.innerHTML = fone.value;
  }
  
  if (contato.value !== '') {
    cont1.innerHTML = contato.value;
    cont2.innerHTML = contato.value;
  }
  
  if (problema.value !== '') {
    pro1.innerHTML = problema.value;
    pro2.innerHTML = problema.value;
  }
  
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você condiciona a ação baseando-se na propriedade `value` do `input`. Logo, se você apagar tudo de uma única vez, a condição não será atendida, já que estará vazio (`''`):

```
if (cliente.value !== '') { // [...]
```

Repare que se você apagar os caracteres dos campos 1 a 1, o último não será removido, já que o `value` passaria a ser `''` (vazio). Pulando, assim, todo o bloco dentro da condição.

Para solucionar, simplesmente remova as condições e deve funcionar como você espera:

```js
        var cliente = document.getElementById('nome');
var fone = document.getElementById('fixo');
var contato = document.getElementById('contato');
var problema = document.getElementById('problema');

var cliente1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[0];
var cliente2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[1];

var tel1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tel')[0];
var tel2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tel')[1];

var cont1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cont')[0];
var cont2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cont')[1];

var pro1 = document.getElementsByClassName('pro')[0];
var pro2 = document.getElementsByClassName('pro')[1];


function insere() {
    cliente1.innerHTML = cliente.value;
    cliente2.innerHTML = cliente.value;
    pro1.innerHTML = problema.value;
    pro2.innerHTML = problema.value;
    cont1.innerHTML = contato.value;
    cont2.innerHTML = contato.value;
    tel1.innerHTML = fone.value;
    tel2.innerHTML = fone.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    Nome <input id='nome' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Cont 1 <input id='fixo' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Cont 2 <input id='contato' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" /> Problema <input id='problema' type='text' value=''
  onkeyup="insere()" />
<br><br><br> problema continua
<br><br><br>
<p>
  Cliente: <span class="cliente"></span><br> 
  Contatos: <span class="tel"></span>\<span class="cont"></span><br>  descrição do problema: <span class="pro"></span>
</p>
<br><br><br> problema resolvido
<br><br><br>
<p>
  Cliente: <span class="cliente"></span><br> 
  Contatos: <span class="tel"></span>\<span class="cont"></span><br> descrição do problema: <span class="pro"></span>
</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // adicionado no snippet
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caraca eu nem se quer pensei nisso, realmente é muito fácil, vlw pela ajuda. No caso eu ainda não estudei a parte de banco de dados, seria fácil introduzir essas informações em uma planilha, tipo do Excel?

Comment: @wilianblack minha sugestão é que continue estudando a base, ao invés de já pular para algo mais complexo. Até porque banco de dados, normalmente, fica no back-end. Vai depender da linguagens e tecnologias que vc vai utilizar. PS: se a minha resposta solucionou seu problema, não se esqueça de aceitar marcando o ✔️. ;)